# Boost Latest Version Install via Apt-get

Tags: boost

Why don't I get latest (>1.62) versions of boost when I try to download from apt-get install?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:boost-latest/ppa
sudo apt-get update
aptitude search boost
```

I only see 1.55 versions. What happen to 1.67?

Comment: It depends on what was tested with your version of Ubuntu, usually the latest isn't what is in the repos. Check with the repo owners. By the way what version of Ubuntu are we talking here?

Comment: Adding PPAs blindly is not good method. Have you checked [its contents](https://launchpad.net/~boost-latest/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) before adding? Last package was dated 2014 in it...

Comment: In this case the reason is because the PPA in question hasn't been updated since 2014.

Answer (score 12):

You can find some other PPAs that have latest version, for example: https://launchpad.net/~mhier/+archive/ubuntu/libboost-latest

Comment: As of today, most of the builds failed, see https://launchpad.net/~mhier/+archive/ubuntu/libboost-latest/+packages